# Using xsl:analyze-string to change multiple words that may repeat

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I wish to change a title in First Letter Caps to proper title case, that is, articles, conjunctions and select prepositions are lowercase. Initially I hoped to achieve this using an xml document of the list of "stopwords" but the closest I have come to success has been through regex in analyze-string. The problem is, as a newbie to xslt, I do not know to make it recursive without looping indefinitely. Also, Ideally this would be a function and not a template. I appreciate any help from the experts out there.

Input:

```
<element>
    <title>The String Is In First Letter Caps And May Have A Word Or Words Such As A, An, Or The And And, But, For, As, At, In, Or When.</title>
</element>
```

xslt:

```
<xsl:template name="proper-case" match="/element/title">
<xsl:param name="title" select="."/> 
    <xsl:analyze-string select="$title" regex="\WA\W|\WAn\W|\WThe\W|\WAnd\W|\WBut\W|\WFor\W|\WNor\W|\WOr\W|\WFSo\W|\WYet\W|\WAs\W|\WAt\W|\WBy\W|\WIf\W|\WIn\W|\WOf\W|\WOn\W|\WTo\W|\WWith\W" flags="i">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="lower-case(.)"/>                               
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>               
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Current Output:

```
<element>
    <title>The String Is in First Letter Caps and May Have a Word or Words Such as A, an, or The and And, but, for, as, at, in, or When.</title>
</element>
```

Desired Output:

```
<element>
    <title>The String Is in First Letter Caps and May Have a Word or Words Such as a, an, or the and and, but, for, as, at, in, or when.</title>
</element>
```

Comment: Which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use? And why do you think you need recursion? It looks to me as if `\b` for a word boundary instead of `\W` could help. I think the specification of the regular expression language for XSLT/XPath does not support `\b` but I think Saxon has an option to support it by using `flags="!i"`.

Comment: @Martin Honnen: I am using oXygen with Saxon-PE 9.4.0.6. I thought I needed recursion because not all instances of the 'stop words' where being processed. My background is in xhtml and css, not in programming, so xslt/xpath is new territory for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better option is to use a sequence for your list of "stopwords".

Example..

**XML Input**

```
<element>
    <title>The String Is In First Letter Caps And May Have A Word Or Words Such As A, An, Or The And And, But, For, As, At, In, Or When.</title>
</element>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Sequence of lower case words.-->
    <xsl:param name="lcw" select="('A','An','The','And','But','For','Nor','Or',
        'So','Yet','As','At','By','If','In','Of','On','To','With','When')"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\w+">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test=".=$lcw and not(position()=1)">
                            <xsl:value-of select="lower-case(.)"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>           
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<element>
   <title>The String Is in First Letter Caps and May Have a Word or Words Such as a, an, or the and and, but, for, as, at, in, or when.</title>
</element>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for advising to use a sequence for the list. That is something I had not seen before. I named the template, removed `<xsl:copy>`, and was able to successfully call the template within the main template.